# "ng lint --fix" is not able to fix my files, but can still identify all the errors expected to be fixed

Tags: angular, tslint, openapi-generator

I'm trying to fix lint issues on files that are automatically generated by [openapi-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli).

Here is an example of file I want to fix:

[image]

To fix those errors, I'm using this command:

```
ng lint openapi --fix
```

The problem is that tslint is able to fix only some errors on these files (the ones created by openapi-generator), for example the rule "**trailing-comma**" is well corrected, when the rules "**max-line-length**" and "**import-spacing**" are not fixed. However these errors are detected as you can see:

[image]

The "openapi" project is defined like that:

[image]

In tslint.json file I defined those rules:

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "trailing-comma": [
      true,
      {
        "multiline": "always",
        "singleline": "never"
      }
    ],
    "arrow-return-shorthand": true,
    "callable-types": true,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "import-blacklist": [
      true
    ],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces",
      2
    ],
    "interface-over-type-literal": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      120
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "log",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-super": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-empty-interface": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-misused-new": true,
    "no-non-null-assertion": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-string-throw": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unnecessary-initializer": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "prefer-const": true,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      true,
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "typeof-compare": true,
    "unified-signatures": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],
    "directive-selector": [
      true,
      "attribute",
      "ngx",
      "camelCase"
    ],
    "component-selector": [
      true,
      "element",
      "ngx",
      "kebab-case"
    ],
    "ban": [
      true,
      "eval",
      "fit",
      "fdescribe",
      {
        "name": "$",
        "message": "please don't"
      }
    ],
    "no-inputs-metadata-property": true,
    "no-outputs-metadata-property": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-lifecycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true,
    "no-unused-variable": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't try to lint generated files... Who cares about those? If you generate those files again, your changes will be discarded. It's not like you should maintain those files.

Comment: Yes indeed, usually I don't do that. But in my current project, some Git Hooks are preventing me to push code to Github because of these generated files, even if they are not committed. So I thought it was the good opportunity to try to clean those ugly generated files.

Comment: Just configure the linter to ignore them.

Comment: Yeah I finally did that. But it's too bad it doesn't work, it must be possible to lint these files too.

Answer (score 1):

We can try running

```
npm run lint -- --fix
```

This will resolve all possible lint errors automatically inside our project.